# Is there a way for GNOME to use only 1 side of Super key?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

I found out via GNOME Tweaks that its possible to bind either left or right side of super key for the Overview.  Is it possible to bind all shortcuts that use the super key to only 1 side of Super key (in my case, the right side) only?

I still need all Super keys to act as it should when running Teradici PCoIP or VMs, especially the left side.

Also, what is the gsettings schema of lock screen?